# External api in aws lambda using python

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Am trying to call an external api from lambda function-python but it always throws time out error even after increasing the time or memory. No vpc. So it should have internet access. The same code works in my local. Any quick help is appreciated. I googled it, but no exact answers. I need to know what vpc setting and role n security to e given. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a private subnet inside your VPC
2. Create a NAT Gateway
3. Create a Route table with your NAT Gateway
4. Assign the Route table to your subnet
5. Attach your Lambda functions to the subnet
6. references this video would definitely help [aws lambda video](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)
    and [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)